# glBufferData syncronization between drawcalls

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I found myself in trouble working with openGl es, in particular feeding the VBO with my data.
Here is the code causing the problem:

```
void Renderer::DrawCurrentData()
{
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (currentVertexIndex) * sizeof(Vertex), vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, (currentIndexIndex) * sizeof(GLushort), indices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, currentIndexIndex, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    currentVertexIndex = 0;
    currentIndexIndex = 0;
    bufVertex = &vertices[currentVertexIndex];
}
```

It works fine until I have only one draw call per frame, so `glBufferData` is called only once for each buffer per frame before calling `glDrawElements`. But if I want to make several draw calls per frame like

1. frame begin
2. `glBufferData`
3. `glDrawElements`
4. .. repeat steps 2,3
5. presentRenderbuffer

Then I got crash in `glBufferData`. This probably happens because of buffer is still locked by previous draw call when I try to feed it with new data. I know I should use synchronization here but I'm not sure how to do that in right way.
I tried to orphan the buffer using `glBufferData` with `NULL` data pointer before providing new data but it din't help. I got the crash on presenting frame buffer in that case. The question is how to manage buffer feeding with new data while the old data still in use?
I tried to use  `GL_STREAM_DRAW` and `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` both showed same results.

Comment: You don't have to take care of synchronization in this case. If you get a crash in the scenario you describe, that's either a driver bug, or some other problem in your code (e.g. the size you pass in is bigger than the actual size of the data).

Comment: I'm using the test environment where I create buffer with rather big data storage(about 10000 vertices) but feeding it with small parts of 100 vertices per draw call where whole scene takes about 200 - 300 vertices to render. So `currentVertexIndex` is always < `vertices` size and thus it's unlikely buffer overfilling.